# What is the iPhone equivalent to the \Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file?

Tags: iphone

I'm working on a web application and need to debug a problem occurring only on the iPhone.

I can reach the site on my dev box by typing its ip address into Safari (on my phone), but the domain is significant to the application, so I'm going to have to update my config in multiple places every time my IP changes.

What would be ideal is if I could configure the iPhone to always point to a specific IP when I enter a specific domain, just like the C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file.

Is there a way to do that without jail breaking my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appended .local to the end of my computer name and it was able to resolve it.

It's not a perfect solution since I'll still have to adjust the settings in the app, but at least I won't have to keep changing it when my IP changes.

According to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/1184) on another SE site, it's Bonjour functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to jailbreak your iPhone, another way would be to use a proxy. Hope I could help :)

Comment: Thanks for the proxy idea.  I'm not willing to jailbreak my phone though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have jailbroken, I think it's `/etc/hosts` (same as the Mac OS X setup)